# Como fazer a classe GenericDAO utilizando o Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, padrão-dao

Eu queria saber qual a melhor forma de fazer uma Dao genérica de um projeto, utilizando o Hibernate e o JPA em java.

Isso tudo para não ficar montando uma DAO da seguinte forma pra cada objeto que irá persistir no banco:

```
public class ProdutoDao {

    private final EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    public ProdutoDao(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    public void adiciona(Produto produto) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(produto);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void remove(Produto produto) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.remove(busca(produto));
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public Produto busca(Produto produto) {
        return em.find(Produto.class, produto.getId());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Produto> lista() {
        return em.createQuery("select p from Produto p").getResultList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Esses links podem te ajudar: 
http://wehavescience.com/2013/02/24/criando-um-dao-generico-com-hibernate/ e http://blog.caelum.com.br/brincando-com-generics-o-bizarregenericdao/. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public abstract class GenericDao<T, I extends Serializable> {

   @Inject
   protected EntityManager entityManager;

   private Class<T> persistedClass;

   protected GenericDao() {
   }

   protected GenericDao(Class<T> persistedClass) {
       this();
       this.persistedClass = persistedClass;
   }

   public T salvar(@Valid T entity) {
       EntityTransaction t = entityManager.getTransaction();
       t.begin();
       entityManager.persist(entity);
       entityManager.flush();
       t.commit();
       return entity;
   }

   public T atualizar(@Valid T entity) {
       EntityTransaction t = entityManager.getTransaction();
       t.begin();
       entityManager.merge(entity);
       entityManager.flush();
       t.commit();
       return entity;
   }

   public void remover(I id) {
       T entity = encontrar(id);
       EntityTransaction tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
       tx.begin();
       T mergedEntity = entityManager.merge(entity);
       entityManager.remove(mergedEntity);
       entityManager.flush();
       tx.commit();
   }

   public List<T> getList() {
       CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
       CriteriaQuery<T> query = builder.createQuery(persistedClass);
       query.from(persistedClass);
       return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
   }

   public T encontrar(I id) {
       return entityManager.find(persistedClass, id);
   }
}
```

Eu sempre utilizo esse. Vê se te ajuda.

Seu DAO ficaria assim:

```
public class ProdutoDao extends GenericDao<Produto, Long> {
    public ProdutoDao() {
       super(Produto.class);
    }   
}
```

Comment: não seria melhor colocar o close/flush do entityManager dentro de um finally depois de um try? caso ocorra alguma exceção...

Answer (score 7):

Eu utilizo algo similar ao que foi indicado pelo @Cassio Danilo. Só que as vezes é interessante que uma DAO seja implementada tanto via JPA quando AdHoc (JDBC).

A minha sugestão é a seguinte:

1. Crie uma interface para a DAO que sugira os métodos de interação principais com a entidade (CRUD)
2. Crie uma classe abstrata de suporte para cada tipo de implementação: JPA e AdHoc.

Ficaria da seguinte forma:

### Dao.class

```
public interface Dao<E extends Serializable, I> {

    E consultarPorId(I id);

    void inserir(E entity);

    E atualizar(E entity);

    void excluir(E entity);

    List<E> consultarTodos();

}
```

### AbstractJPADao.class

```
@Named
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public abstract class AbstractJPADao<E extends Serializable, I> extends AbstractJPASupport implements
    Dao<E, I> {

    private final Class<E> entityClass;

    protected AbstractJPADao(Class<E> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public CriteriaQuery<E> getCriteriaQuery() {
        return this.getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(entityClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void excluir(E entity) {
        this.getEntityManager().remove(entity);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<E> consultarTodos() {
    return this.getEntityManager().createQuery(
        String.format("from %s", this.entityClass.getName()))
        .getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public E consultarPorId(I id) {
        return this.getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void inserir(E entity) {
        this.getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public E atualizar(E entity) {
        return this.getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

}
```

### AbstractJPASupport.class

```
@Named
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public abstract class AbstractJPASupport {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public AbstractJPASupport() {

    }

    public CriteriaBuilder getCriteriaBuilder() {
        return entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    @Inject
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
    checkState(this.entityManager != null,
        "Atencao! Entity Manager nao inicializado.");
    }
}
```

Atente para o detalhe de `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)`. Se estiver utilizando Spring, é um meio interessante de garantir um requisito não funcional para que a sua DAO não seja executada fora de um ambiente transacionado.

Agora, o suporte para implementação JDBC:

### AbstractJDBCDao.class

```
@Named
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public abstract class AbstractJDBCDao {

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall;

    private SimpleJdbcInsert simpleJdbcInsert;

    public AbstractJDBCDao() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    protected final void init() {
        checkState(this.dataSource != null,
            "Atencao! DataSource nao inicializado.");
        final JdbcTemplate rootJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        this.jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(rootJdbcTemplate);
        this.simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(rootJdbcTemplate);
        this.simpleJdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(rootJdbcTemplate);
    }


    public final void setDataSource(final DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    protected final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    protected final SimpleJdbcCall getSimpleJdbcCall() {
        return simpleJdbcCall;
    }

    protected final SimpleJdbcInsert getSimpleJdbcInsert() {
        return simpleJdbcInsert;
    }

}
```

Essa implementação é baseada no Spring JDBC. Pode ser adaptada para outros *frameworks*. Mas a idéia é sugerir que a sua camada de dados possa implementar mais de uma forma de acesso à dados a depender do seu cenário.

[Eu disponibilizei no GitHub um projeto](https://github.com/ricardozanini/spring-config-dao) que pode ser utilizado como referência para trabalhar com Spring + JPA + JDBC utilizando `Profile`s para determinar o tipo de camada de dados que será utilizada no projeto. É apenas para referência. Se tiver algo a colocar, por favor, deixe nos comentários.